# Is it okay to always leave the length field blank for Integers?

Tags: mysql

I've been setting the length field in MySQL for as long as I remember and I just realized I don't know why am I doing it...

For example setting an `INT` type, I always set 11 as length `INT(11)` and `TINYINT(1)`(to store Enable/Disable options) , until just now I wanted to use `MEDIUMINT` and I didn't know what is the max length for this type so I wondered...

I know it's about ZEROFILL, for example INT(4) would display 5 as `0005`, but I still have the following questions

### My questions are:

1. Is it okay to always leave the length blank for Integers? even for Unique keys etc
2. Is there any downside in leaving the length blank?
3. If it is not important and possibly not even good, then why are most people I've seen and the ones who taught me always put length for `INT/MEDIUMINT` etc?

> P.S. I always use `UNSIGNED` never `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL`